# using not function with $this and is(":visible")

Tags: jquery

I have the following html...

```
<button>one</button>
<div class="div1"></div>
<button>two</button>
<div class="div2"></div>
<button>three</button>
<div class="div3"></div>
<button>four</button>
<div class="div4"></div>
```

And this is the jQuery I have used....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

I would like to use `slideToggle()` function (that is to hide) again if others are open(visible). How could I use `not` function with `$this` and `is(":visible")` so that while other is visible the clicked adjacent div is to be shown and others would be closed?

http://jsfiddle.net/VWfv7/

Comment: I'm interested to learn with not and is(":visible")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle().siblings('[class^=div]').slideUp();
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BhKL5/)**

You dont necessarily need to use `:visible` to slideUp. Just slide up the siblings div that particular class pattern.

Or since you want to use :visible and not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
      $('[class^=div]:visible').not($(this).next().slideToggle()).slideUp();
      //Select the class pattern that is visible to slideUp (provide a container possibly)
      //but exclude the clicked element's next div and slideToggle it simultaneously.
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4ff3/)**

Comment: could you please describe about [class^=div]

Comment: @C-Link It is starts with selector. It says element with class starts with `div`. Because you have a pattern there like div1, div2, div3 etc.

Comment: @C-Link If you can give all of those same class name say `.content` then you can just replace it with that class. See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this), $next = $(this).next();
        $this.siblings('div:visible').not($next.next()).slideUp();
        $next.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V8ZaH/)